# Printing output only once inside the loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```py
for i in os.listdir(path_1):
    for j in os.listdir(path_2):
        file_name = (j.split('.')[0])
        if i.__contains__(file_name) and i.endswith('txt'):
            txt_tym = os.path.getctime(path_1 + '/' + i)
            log_tym = os.path.getctime(path_2 + '/' + j)
            if txt_tym >= log_tym:
                print('Issues found in: '+i)
            else:
                print('No issues found')
```

I'm using this program to compare timestamp between two files in two different directory, it has same names but different extension,
I need to show the result in a text document.If there is an issue it will print `Isues found in: filename`.
I need to print `No issues found` only if there is no single files with the issue,
Im using else inside the loop and it prints multiple times.
Please give some suggestions to this

Comment: ... create a list, add all issue-file-names to the list, print the list outside the loop - if list empty print your No issue message

Comment: @PatrickArtner I will try this thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
issues_found = false
for i in os.listdir(path_1):
    for j in os.listdir(path_2):
        file_name = (j.split('.')[0])
        if i.__contains__(file_name) and i.endswith('txt'):
            txt_tym = os.path.getctime(path_1 + '/' + i)
            log_tym = os.path.getctime(path_2 + '/' + j)
            if txt_tym >= log_tym:
                print('Issues found in: '+i)
                issues_found = true

if not issues_found:
    print('No issues found')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept the answer if it helped you.